# Separate dual-head screens with Intel H67

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, slackware, xorg.conf

I am using a Slackware 13.37 system (ASUS P8H67-M LE) with built-in Intel HD graphics, and I am trying to get the monitor outputs to be attached to *seperate* X windows screens (i.e. different $DISPLAY). Letting XOrg do auto-detection results in mirrored monitors, and using Xrandr I can get an extended desktop on a single X display that spans both monitors, neither of which is what I need.

Have seen this referred to in places as Zaphod mode, but most of that goes into multi-seat configurations where each screen has independent mouse/keyboard (sometimes via elaborate running of multiple X-servers). Multi-seating is not a requirement, as what I am trying to build is non-interactive.

I know this has to be done via editing xorg.conf, and it requires using duplicate Display/Monitor/Device sections, but so far I have not been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Two screens (according to X's definition of screen) on a single graphics card? I'm not sure it is possible yet without using Xephyr or xf86-video-nested.

If you're a developer, you might want to test this: http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dri-devel/2012-March/020765.html

If you don't have time: just launch a single X server on both screens (display :0) and then launch 2 Xephyrs (:1 and :2) (or another X server using xf86-video-nested) covering each output. If you use 2 Xephyrs you'll actually have 2 "X displays", not "X screens", but if you're using xf86-video-nested you'll be able to have 2 screens.